# MySQL performance issue when a hash join is used

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization, execution-plan, mysql-8.0

I'm having an issue where the optimizer seems to be doing a full table scan and exhibiting a big performance hit when a hash join is used.

#### Schema and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `px_po_status` (
  `po_status_id` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`po_status_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `px_po_status` (`po_status_id`, `name`)
VALUES
  (0, 'PENDING'),(1, 'SENT'),(3, 'COMPLETE');

CREATE TABLE `px_po` (
  `po_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `po_date` date NOT NULL,
  `po_status_id` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`po_id`),
  KEY `po_date` (`po_date`),
  KEY `po_status_id` (`po_status_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `px_po` (`po_id`, `po_date`, `po_status_id`)
VALUES
  (39647, '2018-10-09', 3),(39648, '2018-10-09', 3),(39649, '2018-10-09', 3),(39651, '2018-10-09', 3),(39653, '2018-10-09', 3),(39654, '2018-10-09', 3),(39655, '2018-10-09', 3),(39657, '2018-10-09', 3),(39658, '2018-10-09', 3),(39659, '2018-10-09', 3),(39660, '2018-10-09', 3),(39661, '2018-10-09', 3),(39662, '2018-10-10', 3),(39663, '2018-10-10', 3),(39665, '2018-10-10', 3),(39666, '2018-10-10', 3),(39667, '2018-10-10', 3),(39668, '2018-10-10', 3),(39669, '2018-10-10', 3),(39670, '2018-10-10', 3),(39671, '2018-10-10', 3),(39672, '2018-10-10', 3),(39673, '2018-10-10', 3),(39674, '2018-10-10', 3),(39675, '2018-10-11', 3),(39676, '2018-10-11', 3),(39677, '2018-10-11', 3),(39678, '2018-10-11', 3),(39679, '2018-10-11', 3),(39680, '2018-10-11', 3),(39681, '2018-10-15', 3),(39682, '2018-10-15', 3),(39683, '2018-10-15', 3),(39684, '2018-10-15', 3),(39685, '2018-10-15', 3),(39686, '2018-10-15', 3),(39687, '2018-10-15', 3),(39688, '2018-10-15', 3),(39689, '2018-10-15', 3),(39690, '2018-10-15', 3);
```

#### Problem query:

```
SELECT
  po.po_id,
  pst.name AS po_status
FROM px_po po
  LEFT JOIN px_po_status pst ON po.po_status_id = pst.po_status_id
ORDER BY po_date DESC
LIMIT 0,25;
```

Running `EXPLAIN` here shows the following:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | po    | NULL       | index | NULL          | po_date | 4       | NULL |   41 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pst   | NULL       | ALL   | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)   |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

#### Workaround #1:

```
SELECT
  po.po_id,
  (SELECT pst.name FROM px_po_status pst WHERE po.po_status_id = pst.po_status_id) as po_status
FROM px_po po
ORDER BY po_date DESC
LIMIT 0,25;
```

Oddly, using a subquery performs much better and gets optimized as I'd expect:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------+---------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                     | rows | filtered | Extra               |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | po    | NULL       | index  | NULL          | po_date | 3       | NULL                    |   25 |   100.00 | Backward index scan |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pst   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 1       | sandbox.po.po_status_id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------+---------------------+
```

#### Workaround #2:

I'm also aware that I can leverage optimizer hints to circumvent the poor performance as outlined here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-table-level. This yields an identical explain to Workaround #1:

```
SELECT /*+ NO_BNL() */
  po.po_id,
  pst.name AS po_status
FROM px_po po
  LEFT JOIN px_po_status pst ON po.po_status_id = pst.po_status_id
ORDER BY po_date DESC
LIMIT 0,25;
```

Couple of notes:

- The problem seems to disappear when there are 4 or more rows in `px_po_status`
- As you might guess, the problem becomes much worse a `px_po` grows. My production db holds over 100,000+ rows and is unacceptably slow without a workaround.
- I've built a fiddle to reproduce all of this here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28ab6f2cc8c53e86e3539a00604026ef
- This was somewhat difficult to reproduce! As you can see from the fiddle above, on a fresh import, you need to `OPTIMIZE TABLE` first or the behaviour is inconsistent.

#### My Question:

Why does the optimizer seem to fail such a basic operation? Is this a bug?

Comment: Why do you `LEFT JOIN px_po_status`, if the join columns are both not null and form an RI constraint. This doesn't make sense, and is probably the reason for the plan choice.

Comment: See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cfcc7c86962b65ad156bd1a1c57ca5ff) for plan differences when you change the LEFT JOIN to an (INNER) JOIN.

Comment: You'll have to test with a realistic dataset - check out what happens [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f4a05dd3727c79f4e9c803e87d11f36) and [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77eef5a9fe68be9b261c8503d2f7a5e0).

Comment: With the FK constraint, the INNER JOIN appears faster...

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle with a full a realistic dataset (17000+ rows).  As you can see, even with `INNER JOIN`, there is still a filesort happening.  For whatever reason, the version they're using here doesn't seem to support `NO_BNL()`, but on my server it behaves as I mentioned above. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4VnSqQgz8hMxE2ZDxw6V7c/0

Comment: That's interesting observation about the FK constraint but still doesn't answer my question.  The optimizer should be smart enough to sort this query without filesort and a full table scan.  I don't understand why the BNL or hash join is ruining performance here and it feels like a bug.

Comment: @Vérace - I tried adding FK constraints on my development db and surprisingly it ended up having a detrimental effect on performance.  Doing INNER JOIN also.  I may need to put together a more robust dataset for Q&A to demonstrate...

Comment: I say that is worth a bug report -- bugs.mysql.com

Comment: This took me forever to consistently reproduce but here's something pretty robust: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6e9e865dd04f79e6e3033933135ed76.  It appears the behaviour changes after running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` - even on a clean import.  Going to file a bug now.

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103190

Answer (score 1):

I found adding an index around `po_status_id` and `name` helps. I dont have a great explanation. I dont know this causes the planner to think it needs to build the entire join despite the limit.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `px_po_status` (
  `po_status_id` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`po_status_id`),
  key (`po_status_id`, `name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

PS. If I were you I would just use an enum for that status.

Comment: interesting... and weird! i was able to reproduce and confirm it works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e477872844467246b8df87bbfe899e8

Comment: Yea its strange. I thought it might be because there was no foreign key, but that doesnt seem to be the case.

Comment: Also note this problem doesn't exist in 5.5 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=a24ee25e5a98f07e8315230ba2688add